# How to source modified system bash-completion file within zsh (oh-my-zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I modified `/etc/bash_completion` (which is just wrapper for `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, and this will load individual scripts within `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/*`) (due to that latest bash-completion's `apt-get` and `apt-fast` completion do not hold `autopurge` definition) but it seems my zsh (oh-my-zsh) shell never load the new definition anyway.

I tried the method which enters bash first, sources `/etc/bash_completion`, then enters zsh again but it seems entering zsh again overwrites the loaded completions again (it works with bash).

I tried majority of online solutions about bash-completion plus zsh issue, including defining `autoload -U +X compinit && compinit` and `autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit` at the head of `~/.zshrc`, using gitfast (which is included in oh-my-zsh by default) that seems to (try to) load system bash-completion file, and [zsh-bash-completions-fallback](https://github.com/3v1n0/zsh-bash-completions-fallback) but no luck.

Directly sourcing `/etc/bash_completion` does not work as it cannot handle `shopt` builtin for bash only, and [zsh-completion](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions) seems to hold only partial definitions, excluding `apt`, `apt-get`, and `apt-fast` completions.

I post my `~/.zshrc` here of which default comments are removed:

```bash
# Workaround: `bashcompinit` first, right after `compinit`
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
autoload -U +X bashcompinit && bashcompinit

# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
    gitfast
    sudo
    web-search
    autojump
    zsh-autosuggestions
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

# `sudo -E` workaround
# You must place this before sourcing $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh.
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

# Workaround: Append local alias with sudo
alias sudo="sudo "

# command-not-found
if [[ -s '/etc/zsh_command_not_found' ]]; then
  source '/etc/zsh_command_not_found'
fi

# apt-fast
alias apt="apt-fast"
alias apt-get="apt-fast"

# zsh-autosuggestions
bindkey '^I' complete-word # tab => complete
bindkey '^[[Z' autosuggest-accept # shift + tab => autosuggest
```

P.S:
On my user account, `~/.bash*` and `~/.profile` do not exist since I remove them all.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution. `bashcompinit` is only for translating the completion-specific `bash` commands into `zsh`, not (as you've seen) for making an arbitrary `bash` completion script work in `zsh`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your help! But then, do you know where `oh-my-zsh` holds its default completion? I could not find it within `~/.oh-my-zsh/`.

Comment: @hurryman2212 You can run `echo $FPATH` to see a list of places where completions are stored. Typically you should find them in `~/.oh-my-zsh/completions` or `~/.oh-my-zsh/cache/completions`.